# Download Google Drive file from url and send with post to backend

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file from an url (chrome drive file) in javascript; and want to send it to my backend (php - laravel).

```
var url = file.downloadUrl !== undefined ? file.webContentLink : file.exportLinks['application/pdf'];

console.log(url) // if I go to url, it downloads the file

if (url !== undefined) {
      var remote = new XMLHttpRequest();
      remote.open('GET', url);
      remote.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + gapi.client.getToken().access_token);
      remote.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      remote.onload = function(e) {
          vm.handle_download(remote.responseText, file, 200); // do something with the fetched content;
      };
      remote.onerror = function(e) {
             vm.handle_download('error response', null, remote.statusText);
      };
      remote.send();
} else vm.handle_download('no downloadable url', {
     file: null,
     status: 'error'
});
```

and on handle

```
handle_download: function (content, file, status) {
        if (status !== 200) {
            console.log('error occured on status')
            return;
        }
}
```

> Failed to load https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1D12321ofd4CNG-m9_Mp4aiDcnibNf&export=download: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://test.dev' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

This is an intended behavior due to [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in the web. Since you're doing this for testing purposes, try this [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/reviews?hl=en) chrome extension.

You can read more about how to implement this in [Using CORS tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). 
 This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present/38237534) may also offer additional insight.